# Conexión de java a sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, ubuntu, windows10

Quiero hacer una conexión de java (en una pc) con sql server (en otra pc) de manera remota, de Windows a Windows ya lo hice.

Pero quiero probar con ubuntu, java NetBeans en una pc con ubuntu y sql server en otra pc con Windows.

Pero no me deja, las dos máquinas hacen ping entre ellas, pero al correr el programa me dice que hay un error, que no se puede hacer conexión con el puerto 1433, que verifique si no hay una instancia ocupándose o un firewall activo.

El firewall ya está abajo y sigue dando error, alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Asegúrate de que la base de datos tenga habilitado el acceso remoto, de otro modo no vas a poder conectarte desde otra máquina aunque no haya firewall.

Comment: Gracias, pero si me conecto desde otra pc con Windows si me deja, solo ocurre el problema con ubuntu, es lo que no entiendo

Comment: Puedes compartir la traza del error?